# Installing Android app in a device

Tags: java, android, installation

I'm a newbie programming for android, I made a simple game some days ago and I tried to install it in a tablet(Android 4.0).

The program works ok, but I got four(4) icons of my app after installation and only one of them is correct(third).

I just want to know how I can to solve this bug so that when I install it in another device it runs ok and get only one icon.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many activities do you have, and how are they declared in your manifest? Are you giving them all the launcher intent filter?

Comment: First try uninstalling the app, removing the icons and reinstalling to make sure it isn't some random quirk. Other than that, as geobits said, check your manifest.

Comment: can you share you manifest file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I got four(4) icons of my app after installation

means you have declared more then one Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` as launch Activity. to show only one Activity as launcher you will need to declare only one Activity with `android.intent.action.MAIN` and `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` intent-filter.
Declare Main Activity which u want to show in Launcher as:

```
<activity android:name="MainActvity"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and other 3 Activity declare as in `AndroidManifest.xml` as :

```
<activity android:name="Actvity_Two"
              android:label="@string/app_name" />
<activity android:name="Actvity_Three"
              android:label="@string/app_name" />
//declare other in same way ..
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because in your manifest you need to change all of your activities EXCEPT your first activity (usually your mainActivity) from:

```
<activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:label="activity name" >
            <intent-filter
                android:label="Your App Name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

to:

```
<activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:label="activity name" >
        </activity>
```

Basically just take the intent-filter out of all your activities that are NOT your main activity. Your main activity needs it so that there is a launcher icon. Hope that helps.